# Ubuntu 11.04 stopped recognizing display driver, and cannot connect to internet

Tags: drivers, gpu-driver, recovery-mode

Every time I reset my computer, I get this message flash across the screen, about how my graphics card settings could not be detected. Moreover, it doesn't seem to be able to connect to the internet, when I run it in 'recovery mode'. When I log in in command prompt, I get this message that `***System Restart Required***`.

Everything seems to be there, but I cannot (auto) mount a USB thumb drive either to get the information off the box.

It's almost as if all my drivers stopped working.

I am not sure where to begin. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Live CD and boot into you system. The USB should work to store files or paste to pastebin with your info.